# An if statement using an object hierachy in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to base a logical statement using a hierachy like below

```
if ((config.elementConfig.curve[0].dataset[0].splitBy = 'my descrete var')) {.....
```

I get the error "error  Unexpected constant condition  no-constant-condition"
from typescript

how do I change it so typescript will like it

Comment: That's not a TypeScript message; perhaps you want to ask about eslint instead?  Are you really intending to *assign* a value (that's what `=` does) instead of *checking* it (which would be `==` or `===`)?

Comment: See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-constant-condition The condition under if is constant as you used an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is that you are trying to do a variable asignment, not an evaluation. You want to use `==`, not `=`.

`=` is used to assign:

```
const myValue = "thing";
```

`==` is used to evaluate.

```
It's complaining that the expression you're giving it doesn't evaluate to something the if condition can check!
if (myValue === "thing") {
```

So you probably intend to have:

```
if ((config.elementConfig.curve[0].dataset[0].splitBy == 'my descrete var')
```